# Is there any other known use of the Graphemes 'ϑ' & 'δ' outside of Avestan?

Tags: orthography, transcription

I think Avestan is really fascinating, but this confuses me. Old Persian uses 'θ' which I think is a better way to write /θ/.

Comment: They’re Greek letters, so yes, there are known uses outside Avestan. The Avestan θ is just a variant of the regular one, similar to how we have single- and double-storey a and g in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet they appear in the latin transcription of avestan though, so their use is a little unusual. I'm pretty sure I've seen Latin delta used in Uralic reconstructions (although the modern Saami languages prefer đ). Not sure about the cursive theta

Comment: @Tristan Delta and theta (along with gamma, beta and lambda) are probably the Greek letters most commonly used in Latin-based transcriptions. Theta, gamma, beta and lambda have the advantage of being part of IPA as well, so they’re fairly obvious choices; delta is less common than ð, but still hardly unheard of. Though I don’t know of any other transcription scheme that specifically uses the cursive theta, either – in other schemes, it would just be a font-dependent variation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't have a source for this, but I suspect even within Avestan analysis there's some amount of font-dependent variation.

Comment: @Draconis I’m no expert on Avestan, but I don’t recall ever seeing the printed variant used for it, neither in reference works nor in text editions. Certainly Bartholomae uses the cursive variant exclusively, and I suspect a lot of usage since is influenced by him.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: yes, they're used in Greek.

ϑ and θ are different graphic variants of the same letter, Greek "theta". The first is a cursive handwritten form, and the second is a standard printed form.

The two have different Unicode representations [for unclear reasons](https://www.opoudjis.net/unicode/letters.html#symbol); some linguists have used θ to represent a voiceless sound and ϑ for the voiced version, but this is rare (the standard symbol for the voiced sound, as you probably already know, is ð). Apart from that, almost nothing distinguishes the two in usage; I don't know why Avestan transliteration tends to use the cursive one and Old Persian the printed one, but I suspect it's just a historical accident that stuck around into the Unicode era.

δ, likewise, is a standard Greek letter ("delta"). It's used in Modern Greek for `/ð/`, so some linguists have used it for that; others have used it just as a variant of ⟨d⟩. For example, if a newly-deciphered writing system seems to have multiple "T-like" and "D-like" symbols, you might transliterate the first ones as ⟨t d⟩ and the second ones as ⟨τ δ⟩, without implying anything in particular about their pronunciation.